# Heroku console giving Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, encoding, irb

Running a heroku console with

```
heroku run console
```

all commands returning UTF-8 characters (like german Umlauts) will result in the following error:

```
irb(main):004:0> Play.all[-2]
   Play Load (27.5ms)  SELECT "plays".* FROM "plays" ORDER BY name asc 
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00E4 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `write'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `printf'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `output_value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'Maybe IRB bug!!
```

I do not really understand the cause of this.
Is there a workaround?

I am using iTerm with a setting of "UTF-8 xterm-color".

## Update

This error completely disappeared for no reason known to me and I can reproduce it neither under ruby 1.9.2p320 nor 1.9.3p448
Typing "\u00E4" into the console now yields "ä" as expected:

```
irb(main):001:0> "\u00E4"
=> "ä"
```

Comment: what's the output for Encoding.default_external and Encoding.default_internal in that console?

Comment: It's <Encoding:UTF-8> both times.

Comment: Do you get the  same error if you just type `"\u00E4"` in the console?

Comment: @kch: Yes. Same error. Does it make sense to update the question to use this simpler case as an example?

Comment: what if you type it in a `heroku run irb` session instead of console?

Comment: @kch: Encoding.default_external: <Encoding:US-ASCII>, Encoding.default_internal: nil, "\u00E4" just throws "\u00E4" back at me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27937/discussion-between-momolog-and-kch)